# How to get the minimum value from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get the lower numeric value from a multi-dimensional array. Just like this.

```
var Things = [
    ["guitar", "99", "guitar.png"],
    ["vinyl", "89", "vinyl.png"],
    ["bed", "25", "bed.png"]
];
```

I would like to return an alert of the lower value, like this:

```
alert() // 25
```

If anybody could help me, would be very grateful.

Comment: It is a very bad practice to name variables with titlecase in JavaScript; in particular, `Array` already exists as the array class, and redefining it can have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Ah ok, so i'll rename this array.

Comment: `Things` is better (as it doesn't overwrite an existing JavaScript built-in), but still bad. Variables, by convention, are in camelcase in JavaScript (words stuck together, first being all lowercase, each consecutive word starting with a capital letter, like so: `arrayOfThings`). This is a point where all JS style guides agree on; here is [Airbnb's](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--camelCase).

Comment: What you are looking for is called "minimum" or "minimum value".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it using sort function:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (parseInt(a[1]) < parseInt(b[1]))
    return -1;
  if (parseInt(a[1]) > parseInt(b[1]))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

var myArray = [
        ["guitar", "99", "guitar.png"],
        ["vinyl", "89", "vinyl.png"],
        ["bed", "25", "bed.png"]
    ];

myArray.sort(compare);

alert(myArray[0][1]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the basic strategy of sorting and then taking the first value as a way to find minimum. Although in general performance is not something to worry too much about, this is going to be much slower (probably `O(n log n)`) than a more straightforward iteration through the object (`O(n)`) to find the minimum.  Among other problems, this requires each string to be parsed as a number up to four times for every single comparison invoked by the sort logic. Then there are edge cases not handled properly such as the array being empty.

Comment: You could also optimize your `compare` function by simply writing `return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [
        ["guitar", "99", "guitar.png"],
        ["vinyl", "89", "vinyl.png"],
        ["bed", "25", "bed.png"]
    ];

min_second = array.reduce(function(a, x) {
  var b = parseFloat(x[1]);
  return a < b ? a : b;
}, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
              
console.log(min_second);
```

`array.reduce` will apply the callback function to the accumulator and each consecutive element, and assign the result to the accumulator; the accumulator starts at +∞. The intent of the callback is that each element whose second value (converted to a number) is less than that becomes the new accumulator. Thus,

- the accumulator starts at +∞
- when compared to 99, becomes 99
- when compared to 89, becomes 89
- when compared to 25, becomes 25

If it were to be compared to a value greater than the current value of the accumulator, it would not change.

Comment: You've essentially rewritten `Math.min` using `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the problem into two parts you can solve separately (or use existing tools to solve):

1. Extract the second element of each sub-array--into a new, one-level array.
2. Find the minimum of an array.

For the first, we use `map` to create a new array from an old one, by applying some transformation to each element. In this case, the transformation is to extract the second element, and convert it to a number, so:

```
Things.map(([,num]) => +num))
```

`[,num]` means to assign the second element of the array passed in to the parameter `num`), and the the plus sign makes sure it's a number. See below for the non-ES6 version.

For the second, we can just use `Math.min`.

Combining these, we can write:

```
Math.min(...Things.map(([,num]) => +num)))
```

`Math.min(...)` passes all the elements in the mapped array (the numbers) as parameters to `Math.min`.

**Obligatory disclaimer**: the `=>` is the ES6 arrow function, the `[,num]` is ES6 parameter destructuring (, and `...` is the ES6 parameter spread operator. These will work only in environments that support ES6 one way or another. Otherwise, fall back to

```
Math.min.apply(0, Things.map(function(elt) { return +elt[1]; }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second elements are the values we are comparing. We can simply do a standard algorithm to iterate through an array and find the lowest value.

```js
var array = [
  ["guitar", "99", "guitar.png"],
  ["vinyl", "89", "vinyl.png"],
  ["bed", "25", "bed.png"]
];
// Assume the first element has the lowest value     
var lowest = +Infinity; // `+` cast to number                       
array.forEach(function(item) {
    if(+item[1] < lowest) lowest = +item[1]; // If we find a lower value update lowest
});
console.log(lowest);
```

Comment: Normal semantics for taking a minimum are that the "default" value (the result if there are no items) is `+Infinity`. That also has the advantage of ensuring your code doesn't fail if the array is empty.

Comment: @torazaburo Perhaps in JavaScript yes, but it's very common to generally use the first element as the starting max/min. Which is how it's done in the standard algorithms (*pseudo*) for finding min/max values.

Comment: Well, this **is** JavaScript. Which "standard algorithms" are you referring to? Can you provide a reference? Using the first element doesn't work at all when there **is** no first element.

Comment: @torazaburo There **is** a first element in this case. More generally there is a check for a empty array before starting. Although it wasn't necessary to include that here.

Comment: Well, to beat a dead horse, solutions should do more than just solve the particular example given by the OP. I don't understand why you would choose to add a special check for empty array when the entire problem could be solved by using `+Infinity` as a default, which is the correct semantics already established by `Math.min`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm just talking about more general algorithmic solutions there. I'll change my answer since it's better to use `+Infinity`. Using the first element is just how I've always seen it done in books on CS algorithms (such as [*"Introduction to Algorithms"*](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844))

Comment: @torazaburo I believe it's because considering *max value* of an empty array to be *Infinity/max* might be considered as a wrong answer. Although I'm not certain on that.

Comment: It seems to differ from language to language. Many languages throw an error. PHP seems to return FALSE and issue a warning. To me, `+Infinity` is intellectually satisfying because it satisfies the invariant that the minimum of an array should be the minimum of the minima of any set of partitions of that array. Personally, I'd rather do the special-casing on the way out, checking for a result of `+Infinity` if I need to, rather than special-casing on the way in, or doing a try/catch like languages which throw would require. Anyway, `+Infinity` seems well established as the JS convention.

Comment: (cont'd) For instance, that's how Underscore behaves. In any case, whatever it does it should not throw a run time error of the form "Cannot access element [1] of undefined" or equivalent IMO.